# Rails: Alternative for bootstrap select?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, html-select

Bootstrap does not style select tags, as such we were forced to use the gem: [bootstrap-select](https://github.com/silviomoreto/bootstrap-select)

But since our application is data intensive, the select dropdowns have quite a number of options. This makes the app really slow (loading the page, clicking the drop down to view the options, and even scrolling up and down the page). Is there a faster solution to get the bootstrap style on a select_tag without compromising performance?

Comment: the problem is you're not styling the dropdown - you're replacing it with an entirely custom Javascript implementation. Bootstrap does style select tags - just not as much as you want, due to browser limitations.

Comment: And using native select shows adequate performance? The bottleneck might be the number of elements in the DOM or in the javascript implementation of the plugin.

Comment: You might also wrap your select boxes in a <% cache do %> block

Comment: We don't have to much data that it causes the native select_tag to slow down, but since JQuery iterates through each option, I might have to go with a pure CSS approach. I just hope cross-browser issues won't be that much of a pain down the road.

Answer (score 3):

Try Select2: http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/
Supports bootstrap styles and has tons of cool stuff.
Also, select2 gem for Rails Asset Pipeline is available on GitHub https://github.com/argerim/select2-rails